# 1and1 windows hosting, web.config permissions

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, web-config, web-hosting, internal-server-error

I'm trying to publish my ASP.NET 4.6 MVC website project to 1and1, but keep receiving this error page.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/njzRx.png

If this link doesn't work, here's the error details:
"HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error"
**Module** - IIS Web Core
**Notification** - Unknown
**Handler** - Not yet determined
**Error Code** - 0x80070005
**Config Error** - Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions
**Config File** - \www\Home\web.config

Oddly enough, when I try to publish the sample website when you start a new project, the same error occurs. When I open the hosting service's file explorer and check the permissions on the web.config file, the IIS_IUSRS already has read and read/execute permissions.

Is there another config file that needs to be edited or have its permissions changed?